How can I display the LUKS decryption screen on all displays?
I have a laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and an encrypted root partition. Unfortunately, the decryption screen (where you enter the password) is only ever shown on the laptops builtin display, not on the external display.
Can I configure it so that the LUKS screen is shown on all displays?

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Wayland)
Kernel: 6.8.0-36-generic
APU: AMD Ryzen 7 8840U with Radeon 780M
RAM: 64 GiB
Disk Capacity: 2 TB
External Monitor: Connected via DP over USB-C

